# Babel seems to break letterspacing of soul package

Tags: babel, soul, letterspacing

This is a MWE of a book I'm working on.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
% \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\so{\MakeUppercase{Book Title}}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\so{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter Title}
\blindtext[11]
\end{document}
```

This is essentially what I want to have.  Except that it ceases to work once I remove the comment in front of the second line.  (Note, this is only about the footer on odd pages!)  Somehow, the `babel` package seems to break the letterspacing of `soul`.  What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `babel`, `\leftmark` produces a quite complicated sequence of commands and `\so` gives up very early.

You can use `microtype` instead.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
\fancyfoot[LE]{\textls{\MakeUppercase{Book Title}}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\textls{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter Title}
\blindtext[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]